# Vue Cascading Autocomplete object keys

Tags: javascript, vue.js, select, autocomplete

I try to 3 or 4 level cascading autocomplete in vue js. But it is not working correctly. here is the orjinal [codepen](https://codepen.io/ygtalp/pen/ZEOLKQq)

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-layout wrap>
          <v-flex xs3 md3>
            <v-autocomplete v-model="category" :items="categories" label="Category"  full-width solo hint="Random set of categories">
            </v-autocomplete>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex xs3 md3>
            <v-autocomplete v-model="purpose" :items="purposes" label="Purpose"  full-width solo hint="Based on the selected category">
            </v-autocomplete>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

js

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      model: null,
      product: null,
      category: null,
      purpose: null,
      categoriesPurposes: {
        "Farm Animals": ["cow", "sheep", "hen"],
        Directions: ["left", "right", "up", "down"],
        Time: ["past", "present", "future"],
        Element: ["air", "water", "tierra", "fire"]
      }
    };
  },
  computed: {
    categories() {
      return Object.keys(this.categoriesPurposes);
    },
    purposes() {
      if (!this.category) {
        return null;
      } else {
        return this.categoriesPurposes[this.category];
      }
    }
  }
});
```

i tried 1 more level deep but second autocomplete looks object.

i changed the data like:

```
categoriesPurposes: {
        Asia:{
            "Farm Animals": ["cow", "sheep", "hen"],
            Directions: ["left", "right", "up", "down"],
            Time: ["past", "present", "future"],
            Element: ["air", "water", "tierra", "fire"]
          }
       }
```

but this time second autocomplete data seems object

how can i access the keys and show them?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You gave an Object which is an illegal value defined by Vuetify

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop 'items'. Expected Array, got Object
```

The problem is you're returning `this.categoriesPurposes[this.category]` which in your case is an Object not an Array of Objects. For you to be able to pass an Array of Objects you need to look how the specification is by Vuetify.

[link to docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/#props)

This should work

```
      categoriesPurposes: {
        "Farm Animals": [
          {
            text: "This is the cow",
            value: "cow",
          },
          {
            text: "This is the sheep",
            value: "sheep",
          },
          {
            text: "This is the hen",
            value: "hen"
          }
        ],
        Directions: ["left", "right", "up", "down"],
        Time: ["past", "present", "future"],
        Element: ["air", "water", "tierra", "fire"]
      }
```

made a [a working example here](https://codepen.io/maarteNNNN/pen/ZEOLXKV)

Comment: doesn't work. i am new this like coding. i just want to cascading autocomplete. searched some codepen and found posted one. so i wanted to change to 3 level cascading and wrapped datas with key. i know i am missing something but i tried your answer but nothing change. thanks anyway.

Comment: Do you want to have 3 inputs or 3 selections? Let me be more clear do want select Asia and subselect Farm Animals in the same input or do you want an input for each of them?

Comment: sorry for not saying clearly. i want to have 3 selection like:
parent-drop1      child-drop2     subchild-drop3
and these 3 autocompletes goes to parent to child.

if parent change, child and subchild change too.